# cannot pass string to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm using javascript and I try to pass a string to a function , like so

```
        //example string
        var f="a";

//add button that sends the value of f to the function
     document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML="<input type='button' id='myButton' value='Click here' onclick='gothere("+f+");'> ";

    function gothere(a){
    alert(a);
    }
```

I never see the alert and in console I see `a is not defined` (refers to the f I guess?)

If i set the f `var` to be a number then I see the alert.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I was thinking maybe something like

```
var buttonnode= document.createElement('input');

document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(buttonnode);
buttonnode.onclick=gothere(f);
```

Wont work for the same reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your HTML get's rendered, you get `onclick='gothere(a);'`, but the actual `a` variable doesn't exist in this context, you want to pass the value of f, as a string, so you'll need to  use `onclick='gothere(\""+f+"\");'`. Note the extra quotes inside the parens. This will render to `onclick='gothere("a");'` thus passing the string.

When using a number, it works, because calling `onclick='gothere(5);'` is valid, since a variable can't be named `5`, and it passes the number.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't have an `a` in your code. You are using variable `f` to denote `a`. So using this would help you:

```
var f="a";
// write the remains of the code as they are..

function gothere(f) {
  alert(f);
}
```

Now when you'll call the function, there will be an alert of `a` in the browser.

Also, try wrapping the content in `""` double qoutes to let the code understand that this is a string not a character.

For onclick use

```
onclick='gothere(" + f + ")'
```

And now, its onto you to write the value. Maybe the issue is because you're not writing the value for the `f`.

Try inpecting the error. I am sure there won't be anything.

Or try using the attribute field and change it using `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

How about fixing your code ? You are missing the quotes around the value denoted by variable F.
Hence, when variable F is parsed, the function becomes `gothere(a)` . while `a` is not a defined variable (but its a value) and hence the error.

Try this !

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML="<input type='button' id='myButton' value='Click here' onclick='gothere(\""+f+"\");'> ";
```

The modified part is  `onclick='gothere(\""+f+"\");'> "`

This should work for you !

Answer (score 1):

**function parameter string value image dynamically from JSON**. Since item.product_image2 is a URL string, you need to put it in quotes when you call changeImage inside parameter.

My Function Onclick inside pass parameter.

```
items+='<img src='+item.product_image1+' id="saleDetailDivGetImg">';
items+="<img src="+item.product_image2+"  onclick='changeImage(\""+item.product_image2+"\");'>";
```

My Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage(img)
 {
    document.getElementById("saleDetailDivGetImg").src=img;
    alert(img);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use single quotation marks for value arguments (see @Nis or @CDspace answer).
2. Better way to handling dynamic clicks or other events is **event binding**. See jQuery event binding for example.